# polkit.d - no such file or directory

Tags: polkit, consolekit

When consolekit starts on my system, polkitd also starts and during that startup, I see an error message complaining that polkitd cannot find files that exist.

I checked the permissions and they seem fine, so I'm wondering if it is a configuration issue for the content inside of the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the return statement, instead of returning polkit.Result.YES, a simple "yes" works.  I think I was referencing the wrong constant, so I'm glad it was something simple.